# Is a binomial a sum of Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I know that, if $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim \text{Ber}(p)$ are independent, then $X_1+\ldots+X_n\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$.

My question is: if $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, is it true that there exist independent random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\text{Ber}(p)$ such that $X(\omega)=X_1(\omega)+\ldots+X_n(\omega)$ for all $\omega\,$?

EDIT: I would like an **analytic** proof of this fact (if it is true).

Comment: Let $X_j$ be the $j^{\mathrm{th}}$ bit in the binary representation of $X$ - assuming the sample space has at least $2^n$ elements.

Comment: The result fails without some additional hypothesis on the sample space since the collection $(X_k)$ requires a space of size at least $2^n$ while $X$ can be realized on a sample space of size $n+1$.

Comment: Is your question regarding whether these Bernoulli r.v.s exist in the probability space? That's sorta the wrong question, usually we just build a large enough probability space to do whatever we want. But yes, on a rather small sample space you can fail to have enough independent Bernoulli r.v.s to assemble a binomial r.v. from them, even though you can build a binomial r.v. from scratch. Intuitively the smaller probability space does not resolve the distinction between, say, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, aggregating them both into a single state $1$.

Comment: @Did Good point, my construction would require $2^n$ distinct elements in the sample space in order for the strings e.g. $X_n\cdots X_1$ to be distinguishable, probabilistically.

Comment: @A.E How does one realize the random variables from this formula? Your comment does not even touch that...

Comment: @Math1000 At least $2^n$, yes, but the sample space should also be suitable for $X$ hence it is not so simple to determine if a given sample space of size at least $2^n$ solves the problem.

Comment: One can build $(X_k)$ if and only if **each event $[X=i]$ has a measurable equipartition of size ${n\choose i}$**, that is, for each $i$ from $0$ to $n$, there exists ${n\choose i}$ disjoint events $A^i_j$ with equal probabilities $P(A^i_j)={n\choose i}^{-1}P(X_n=i)=p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$. Then one can define $(X_k)$ with the correct distribution, as being constant with $X_1+\cdots+X_n=i$ on each $A^i_j$. For example, $A^1_j$ could be $[X_j=1]\cap[\forall \ell\ne j,X_\ell=0]$ for each $j$ from $1$ to ${n\choose 1}=n$.

Comment: For an example of a sample space of size $\geqslant4$ and a random variable $X$ Bin$(2,\frac12)$ which cannot be written as the sum of two independent Ber$(\frac12)$ random variables, assume that $\Omega=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ with $P(\{a\})=P(\{b\})=P(\{c\})=P(\{d\})=\frac18$, $P(\{e\})=x$ and $P(\{f\})=\frac12-x$ for some $x$ in $[0,\frac12]$, and let $X(a)=X(b)=0$, $X(c)=X(d)=2$ and $X(e)=X(f)=1$. Then $X$ is indeed Bin$(2,\frac12)$ but, for every $x\ne\frac12$, $[X=1]=\{e,f\}$ has no equipartition of size $2$ hence there exists no $(X_1,X_2)$ i.i.d. Ber$(\frac12)$ such that $X=X_1+X_2$.

Comment: *Typo: for every $x\ne\frac14$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. As @Did pointed out, we can construct a $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable on a probability space with $n+1$ elements. Consider $\Omega = \{0,1,2\}$ with \begin{align}\mathbb P(\{0\})&=(1-p)^2\\\mathbb P(\{1\})&= 2p(1-p)\\ \mathbb P(\{2\})&=p^2 \end{align}
and $X(\omega)=\omega$. If $X=X_1+X_2$ where $X_1, X_2$ take values in $\{0,1\}$ then from
\begin{align}
0 &= X(0) = X_1(0) + X_2(0)\\
2 &= X(2) = X_1(2) + X_2(2)
\end{align}
we see that $X_1(0)=X_2(0)=0$ and $X_1(2)=X_2(2)=1$. It is clear that $X_1$ and $X_2$ cannot be independent.

An example where the answer is "yes" is given by the $\Omega = \{H,T\}^n$ (i.e. the outcomes are $n$ tosses of a coin), $$\mathbb P(\{\omega\}) = p^j (1-p)^{n-j},\; \omega\in\Omega$$ where $j$ is the number of "heads" in $\omega$, and $X$ again the number of "heads" in $\omega$. For $\omega = (\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)$, define $X_j$ by $X_j(\omega) = \mathsf 1_{\omega_j=1}$. It follows from the binomial theorem that $$\mathbb P(X_j=1) = p = 1 - \mathbb P(X_j=0),\; j=1,2,\ldots,n, $$
and by construction, $$X=\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$$ with the $X_j$ independent.

Comment: I don't understand $X_j(\omega)=X(\omega)_j$. Are not $X(\omega)$ and $X_j(\omega)$ in $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: @jxm Ah, let me fix the notation.